# Add a guide overlay to a flex video component (Mobile Camera).

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, flex4, zxing

I am working on a mobile app in flex that reads QRCodes. In order to help the user align the code I want to place a guide box in the center of the video panel. I am using a PNG that contains a green rectangle and transparent background. I am open to all suggestions. The following shows how everything is working.

outside of flash script:

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" horizontalAlign="center" id="vg">

        <s:SpriteVisualElement id="sv" width="100%" height="250"/>

    </s:VGroup>
```

in create camera method:

```
camera = Camera.getCamera();
camera.setMode(360, 360, 24);

videoDisplay.x = 360;
sv.addChild(videoDisplay);

videoDisplay.attachCamera(camera);
videoDisplay.rotation = 90;
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I have already tried several things and usually the image displays near the camera video window instead of over it.

Comment: What if you drew the overlay as a full screen image over the video playback and set the alpha blend on the overlay to something v low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few nicely placed groups will do it... like this:

```
    <s:Group width="100%" height="250">
        <s:SpriteVisualElement id="sv" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        <!-- nesting in another VGroup will allow you to center the image on the video -->
        <s:VGroup verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" 
                  width="100%" height="100%">
            <!-- depending on size of the image, you might want to set scaling/maxWidth etc here -->
            <s:Image source="{yourImagePathOrClass}" />
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Group>
```